# i want to get the pid of picture having maximum likes. how can i do that?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have tried this

```
select max(c) from (select pid as p, count(likeuid) as c from likes group by pid);
```

But this gives me only the count of picture which is liked most.
I want pid of the picture which is liked most.

this is my mini instadb database
[tables description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLCFL.png)

likes table

```
CREATE TABLE  "LIKES" 
   (    "PID" NUMBER(6,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LIKEUID" NUMBER(6,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COMMENTS" VARCHAR2(140) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "LIKES_UK1" UNIQUE ("PID", "LIKEUID", "COMMENTS") ENABLE
   ) ;ALTER TABLE  "LIKES" ADD CONSTRAINT "LIKES_FK2" FOREIGN KEY ("PID")
      REFERENCES  "PICTURES" ("PID") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE;ALTER TABLE  "LIKES" ADD CONSTRAINT "LIKES_FK3" FOREIGN KEY ("LIKEUID")
      REFERENCES  "USERS" ("USERID") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE;
```

Comment: don't post image of schema  only  .. post also  a text schema.. add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query worked for me

```
select pid from likes group by pid having count(pid)=(select max(count(pid)) from likes group by pid);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the one person with max likes, I think this SQL is what you want:

```
SELECT
    p, 
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY c DESC) toplikes
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        pid AS p, 
        count(likeuid) AS c 
    FROM 
        likes 
    GROUP BY 
        pid
    ORDER BY 
        count(likeuid) DESC
    )
WHERE 
    toplikes = 1
```

Comment: I bet this won't run.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
select pid, max(c) from likes
join(select pid, count(likeuid) as c from likes group by pid) a on a.pid = likes.pid
group by pid
```

Comment: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "A"."PID": invalid identifier

Comment: that was a typo, I changes it a bit and that error shouldn't come up now.